# Efficient way to swap bytes in python

Tags: python, arrays, swap, endianness

I have some `bytearray` with length of `2*n`:

```
a1 a2 b1 b2 c1 c2
```

I need to switch bytes endian in each 2-byte word, and make:

```
a2 a1 b2 b1 c2 c1
```

Now I use next approach but it is very slow for my task:

```
converted = bytearray([])
for i in range(int(len(chunk)/2)):
   converted += bytearray([ chunk[i*2+1], chunk[i*2] ])
```

Is it possible to switch endian of `bytearray` by calling some system/libc function?

---

Ok, thanks to all, I timed some suggestions:

```
import timeit

test = [
"""
converted = bytearray([])
for i in range(int(len(chunk)/2)):
   converted += bytearray([ chunk[i*2+1], chunk[i*2] ])
""",
"""
for i in range(0, len(chunk), 2):
    chunk[i], chunk[i+1] = chunk[i+1], chunk[i]
""",
"""
byteswapped = bytearray([0]) * len(chunk)
byteswapped[0::2] = chunk[1::2]
byteswapped[1::2] = chunk[0::2]
""",
"""
chunk[0::2], chunk[1::2] = chunk[1::2], chunk[0::2]
"""
]

for t in test:
    print(timeit.timeit(t, setup='chunk = bytearray([1]*10)'))
```

and result is:

```
$ python ti.py
11.6219761372
2.61883187294
3.47194099426
1.66421198845
```

So in-pace slice assignment with a step of 2 now is fastest. Also thanks to Mr. F for detailed explaining but I not yet tried it because of `numpy`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use slice assignment with a step of 2:

```
byteswapped = bytearray(len(original))
byteswapped[0::2] = original[1::2]
byteswapped[1::2] = original[0::2]
```

Or if you want to do it in-place:

```
original[0::2], original[1::2] = original[1::2], original[0::2]
```

Timing shows that slicing massively outperforms a Python-level loop for large arrays:

```
>>> timeit.timeit('''
... for i in range(0, len(chunk), 2):
...     chunk[i], chunk[i+1] = chunk[i+1], chunk[i]''',
... 'chunk=bytearray(1000)')
81.70195105159564
>>>
>>> timeit.timeit('''
... byteswapped = bytearray(len(original))
... byteswapped[0::2] = original[1::2]
... byteswapped[1::2] = original[0::2]''',
... 'original=bytearray(1000)')
2.1136113323948393
>>>
>>> timeit.timeit('chunk[0::2], chunk[1::2] = chunk[1::2], chunk[0::2]', 'chunk=
bytearray(1000)')
1.79349659994989
```

For small arrays, slicing still beats the explicit loop, but the difference isn't as big:

```
>>> timeit.timeit('''
... for i in range(0, len(chunk), 2):
...     chunk[i], chunk[i+1] = chunk[i+1], chunk[i]''',
... 'chunk=bytearray(10)')
1.2503637694328518
>>>
>>> timeit.timeit('''
... byteswapped = bytearray(len(original))
... byteswapped[0::2] = original[1::2]
... byteswapped[1::2] = original[0::2]''',
... 'original=bytearray(10)')
0.8973060929306484
>>>
>>> timeit.timeit('chunk[0::2], chunk[1::2] = chunk[1::2], chunk[0::2]', 'chunk=
bytearray(10)')
0.6282232971918802
```

Comment: @user3479125: I've corrected an inefficiency in how my code was creating the `byteswapped` array; it should now outperform the explicit loop if you redo your timings. I've also added an in-place slice-based solution that should be even faster. Also, if you try your timings with larger arrays, you'll find that an explicit loop scales much worse than slicing due to greater interpreter overhead.

Answer (score 3):

I can repeat the result of in-place slice method from @user2357112 supports Monica. But if  data size is ten time as big, it is twice slower compared with array.byteswap():

```
>>> timeit.timeit('chunk[0::2], chunk[1::2] = chunk[1::2], chunk[0::2]', 'chunk=bytearray(10000)')
12.54664899999625

>>> timeit.timeit('a=array.array("H",chunk);a.byteswap();chunk=a.tobytes()', 'import array;chunk=bytearray(10000)')
6.398380300001008
```

Comment: Is the impact of `import array` relevant?

Comment: @ack No. Because when we bother to optimize we probably are averaging the impact with many loops. When ```import array``` is moved into the loop, in the 1000 case the impact is only several percent. In fact  I think ```chunk=a.tobytes()``` is not necessary to be there (saving 10%).

Answer (score 2):

If you use numpy's `frombuffer` function, you can construct a numpy `ndarray` that actually shares the physical memory of the `bytearray`, and then swapping actions could be done in-place rather than in a copy.

You can simply perform the same indexing directly on `byt`, such as

```
byt[i] = byt[i+1]
```

but getting a handle to the buffered array with an explicit type in numpy often lets you do much more, particularly with `bytearray` which is very limited on its own.

Be careful though. Even though at the Python level, `bytearray` represents unsigned 8-bit integer values (0-255), the actual underlying C implementation, in `bytearrayobject.h` uses a plain `char` for the byte values ([see here for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35835785/does-python-bytearray-use-signed-integers-in-the-c-representation)). If using numpy for this, you probably want to specify the optional `dtype` argument to `frombuffer`, with `dtype=numpy.ubyte`.

```
import numpy as np
byt = bytearray(range(256))
npbyt = np.frombuffer(byt, dtype=np.ubyte)

for i in range(0, len(npbyt)-1, 2):
    temp = npbyt[i]
    npbyt[i] = npbyt[i+1]
    npbyt[i+1] = temp

print(list(byt))
```

It prints

```
[1, 
 0,
 3,
 2,
 5,
 4,
 ...
 255,
 254]
```

I ran into some of these issues while working on a small side project called [buffersort](https://github.com/spearsem/buffersort), which can perform in-place sorting on Python objects that implement the write able buffer protocol, as `bytearray` does.

If you're interested in grabbing the Cython source from there, there is a simple helper function `_swap` that would make it easy to do what you want. It's probably highly overkill for your use case though.

Answer (score 2):

From some answers in [How to byte-swap a 32-bit integer in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36096292/efficient-way-to-swap-bytes-in-python)

```py
import struct

def htonl_slice(data):
    byteswapped = bytearray(4)
    byteswapped[0::4] = data[3::4]
    byteswapped[1::4] = data[2::4]
    byteswapped[2::4] = data[1::4]
    byteswapped[3::4] = data[0::4]
    return byteswapped

def htonl_slice_2(data):
    byteswapped = bytearray(len(data))
    byteswapped[0::4] = data[3::4]
    byteswapped[1::4] = data[2::4]
    byteswapped[2::4] = data[1::4]
    byteswapped[3::4] = data[0::4]
    return byteswapped

def htonl_struct(data):
    return struct.pack(">L", struct.unpack("<L", data)[0])

def swap32(data):
    return [struct.unpack("<I", struct.pack(">I", i))[0] for i in data]

def htonl_shift(x):
    return (((x << 24) & 0xFF000000) |
            ((x <<  8) & 0x00FF0000) |
            ((x >>  8) & 0x0000FF00) |
            ((x >> 24) & 0x000000FF))    

def test(self):

    data = [struct.pack('<L', i) for i in range(1000000)]

    start = time.time()
    for d in data:
        x = htonl_slice(d)
    end = time.time()
    print("htonl_slice %f" % (end - start))
    
    start = time.time()
    for d in data:
        x = htonl_struct(d)
    end = time.time()
    print("htonl_struct %f" % (end - start))

    data = [i for i in range(1000000)]
    start = time.time()
    for d in data:
        x = htonl_shift(d)
    end = time.time()
    print("htonl_shift %f" % (end - start))

    start = time.time()
    x = swap32(data)
    end = time.time()
    print("swap32 %f" % (end - start))

    data = bytearray()
    for i in range(1000000):
        data += struct.pack('<L', i)

    start = time.time()
    x = htonl_slice_2(data)
    end = time.time()
    print("htonl_slice_2 %f" % (end - start))
```

And the results are:

```
htonl_slice   3.041000
htonl_struct  0.626000
htonl_shift   0.864000
swap32        0.533000
htonl_slice_2 0.025000
```

I understand that `htonl_shift` works with `int`s instead of bytearrays.

It is interesting to see that `swap32` is pretty fast, but for a 4 MB array `htonl_slice_2` is by far the fastest.

Answer (score 1):

You could also swap them in place and use the original array.

```
chunk = bytearray([1,2,3,4])

for i in range(0, len(chunk), 2):
    chunk[i], chunk[i+1] = chunk[i+1], chunk[i]
```